# how to count the current posts terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, count

Hi i'm trying to figure out how to count the number of terms for the current post, i've tried using `wp_get_object_terms`() and

```
<?php
$title = get_post($post->ID);
$numTerms = wp_count_terms( $title->post_type, array(
'hide_empty'=> false,
'parent'    => 0
) ); ?>
```

without any luck, does anyone have a solution for this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_count_terms` function counts terms in a given taxonomy (e.g. total number of categories, total number of tags).

To get what you want, get the terms for the post and just count them `count( wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args ) );`. Or, assuming that in real life you might need those terms later:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $args );
$terms_count = count ( $terms );
```